# Retrieving the value selected from a listfield

Tags: java, blackberry

I used a static list and checked the value selected, and it was correct. Now applying the same code to a list which is dynamically populated from SQLite db is showing a junk value for the value clicked. Here is the code

```
class mal2eng extends MainScreen
                            implements ListFieldCallback {


    private ListField _listfield;


    private Item _selected = null; 



    private Vector _listVector = new Vector();



    mal2eng() {

        Database d;
        try
                {
                    URI myURI=URI.create("file:///SDCard/Databases/MyTestDatabase.db");
                    d=DatabaseFactory.open(myURI);
                   Statement st=d.createStatement("SELECT malLetter FROM MalayalamLetter");
                   st.prepare();
                   net.rim.device.api.database.Cursor c=st.getCursor();
                   Row r;

                   while(c.next())
                   {

                    r=c.getRow();
                    String w=r.getString(0);

                    _listVector.addElement(new Item(w));
                   }
                   st.close();
                   d.close();
                   }
                     catch ( Exception e ) 
        {         
            System.out.println( e.getMessage() );
            e.printStackTrace();
        }                      


        this.setTitle("List");


        _listfield = new ListField(_listVector.size());
        _listfield.setCallback(this); 
             FontManager.getInstance().load("DC124.TTF", "MyFont", FontManager.APPLICATION_FONT) ;
        {
             try {
                FontFamily typeface = FontFamily.forName("MyFont");
                Font myFont = typeface.getFont(Font.PLAIN, 25);
                _listfield.setFont(myFont);
                this.add(_listfield);
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();}

            }



    }

    protected boolean onSavePrompt() {
        return true;
    }

    protected void makeMenu( Menu menu, int instance ) {

    }

    public void drawListRow(ListField list, Graphics g, int index, int y, int w) {
        Item ToDraw = (Item) this.get(list, index);
        int drawColor = Color.BLACK;

        g.setColor(drawColor);
        g.drawText(ToDraw.word, 0, y, 0, w);
    }


    public Object get(ListField list, int index) {

         return _listVector.elementAt(index);
    }

    public int getPreferredWidth(ListField list) {
        return Display.getWidth();
    }

    public int indexOfList(ListField listField, String prefix, int start) {

        return start;
    }

    public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    Field focus = _listfield.getLeafFieldWithFocus();


    if (focus instanceof ListField) {
        ListField listField = (ListField)focus;
       String w=listField.getCallback().get(listField,listField.getSelectedIndex()).toString();
      UiApplication ui = UiApplication.getUiApplication();
      ui.pushScreen(new ListFieldScreen(w));
    }
    return true;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A small thing you can do as you are getting the Data from database use a dataStructure like Vector or something of that kind . Put the data in the vector which you are getting from the database.**override** the `navigationClick method` like below ...

```
navigationClickMethod(int, int ){
 //Call getSelectedindex here 

 // And use this to call Element at the selected index of the dataStructure you have 

}
```

this is the simplest way to get the selected values from the list ...

Comment: I am using a vector and also navigation click method as i have posted above.In the above code the last dialog shows the value selected in previous static list i did before but not now .any other way?

Comment: you are getting the data in the vector as it is in the Database right. and showing that to the list i am assuming this is it? Then whats the problem??

Comment: Just do the logic as you click on the list you are getting selected value of the row as an int type so can't you call the vector.elementAt(the index you got from the navigation click method )

Comment: ya tried that too.I did it inside the navigation click method but that couldn't make a difference

Comment: used the below code and it worked fine                          public boolean navigationClick(int status, int time) {
    Field focus = this.getLeafFieldWithFocus();
  

    if (focus == _lf) {
        _selectedItem = (Items) this.get(_lf, _lf.getSelectedIndex());
      if ( _selectedItem != null ) {
                String name =_selectedItem.m ;
                             
             
                 UiApplication ui = UiApplication.getUiApplication();
      ui.pushScreen(new DisplayScreen(name));
            }
     
    }
    return true;
}
    }